# I2C communication not working

Tags: microcontroller, fpga, i2c, xilinx, pullup

I am trying to read data from / write data to a Xilinx Zedboard (FPGA platform) using an external microcontroller via the I2C bus. The schematic for this would currently look as follows:

[image]

As you can see in the schematic, the microcontroller uses 1k pull-up resistors for the I2C bus.

I noticed that after the first transaction, the microcontroller will not read/write anymore data.

I cannot debug this on the microcontroller because I cannot make any changes to the microcontroller software. The microcontroller has been verified to work correctly with other I2C peripherals.

When I look at an oscilloscope trace, I can see the Zedboard does not pull down the SDA line to the logic low level of the microcontroller while sending an ACKnowledge. I think this might be the reason why the transaction fails. See the capture below, where you can see the SDA low of the Zedboard is about 600 mV above the SDA low of the microcontroller.

[image]

I think the reason for this might be because the pull-up resistors are quite low. However, I cannot make any changes to the microcontroller board, and therefore I cannot replace them for higher resistances.

Do you have any idea what might be the problem here and how I can solve this?

Thank you and regards.

Comment: Are there long wires between boards? Are SDA and SCL sent over neighbouring wires? There seems to be unexpectedly high level of crosstalk, considering the resistors are 1k.

Comment: The wires are about 50 cm long and they are not sent over neighbouring wires.

Comment: Do you power the Zedboard through the very same GND line? If yes, the resistance of the GND line may result in a ground lift. Use thicker or more wires for GND.

Comment: So what kind of cable is it and what is the pinout then? I2C sent over 50cm of poor wiring might be unreliable, but when everything is properly designed it can work over many meters (as in VGA, DVI and HDMI).

Comment: Try using a level translator to buffer your signals or if available a I2C buffer chip such as a P82B715T.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The voltage you see on your bus line corresponds to a resistance of the low side switch of something above 200 ohm.

A quick glance in the schematic of the ZedBoard shows, that some input pins have a 200 ohm series resistor, probably for ESD protection. I assume you used such a pin for your I2C communication, but since you did not tell us how exactly you connected the µC to the ZedBoard I can't say for sure.

You will have to use an input pin without this series resistance to get a good low level.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I connected the I2C pins to JA2 and JA3. Now I also looked at the schematic and I saw all PMOD pins which do not use the 200 Ohm resistors are differential. Do you know if it can do any harm when use the differential pins for I2C?

Comment: I'm actually not sure, but I suspect that the pins can be configured any way you want. Make sure that the pins are configured to support the high voltage of the 3.3V digital I2C lines. Probably the default for differential configuration is some lower voltage input. You have to dig in the datasheet to get the details.

Comment: I tried it with the differential pins and it solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use an I2C buffer so that you can use your own pull-ups on the device side.